# Pushing changes to sub-repository using Visual Studio 2019

Tags: git, azure-devops, git-submodules, visual-studio-2019, team-explorer

I'm trying to handle two repositories (`repo B` being child of `repo A`) by only working on the parent `repo A`.

Current sub-repository handling:

[image: Current sub-repository handling]

Basically, my objective is to push changes to `repo B` whenever I push `repo A` (if there are changes to `repo B` folder).

I tried achieving this with Submodules, but it seems vs2019 won't even recognize specific changes in the submodule folder. It will just display that the submodule has changed but never really allowing me to push. Most of the time I just get `fatal: unexpected sequence in commit output`.

Both my repositories are in Azure DevOps. I've also considered making a Pipeline that runs a `.sh script` to automatically push another repository on registered pushes. Could only get `repo A` trying to push the entirety of itself on `repo B`.

Is this really the only way to achieve what I'm trying to do? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio 2019 understands that a submodule is dirty, but it does not currently have the ability to push both the parent and submodule at the same time.  This is because Visual Studio currently only opens one repo at a time.  In your scenario, Visual Studio is only directly working with the parent repo.

A workaround, while definitely not ideal, is to open the submodule repo directly first.  Commit the changes there, and push it.  Then switch back to the parent repository to consume the changes and then push the parent.

The ability to work in multiple repos has been requested by customers, and is something that will be considered for a future release.

Hope this helps.

Comment: While I now know that vs cannot handle submodules at all, the workaround is not really helpful. It would be the same as doing it manually, if not faster. I had made a quick script that pushes changes to the sub-repo and closes itself, but I want to automate it.


I have found a solution, although I don't really like it. I'm sure there's a better way to do this but I couldn't find it.
As of now I am using Azure Pipelines to execute a `bash script` that re-initializes and pushes changes to the sub-repository whenever there are changes to the main repository. It works, but no history.